# Problemas Para realizar búsqueda en tiempo real

Tags: javascript, ajax, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, webservice

Tengo la siguiente duda, estoy trabajando en un proyecto donde desde la solution, logro hacer una búsqueda en tiempo real por medio de un WEBSERVICE, este WEBSERVICE tiene un archivo JSON, el cual contiene datos para la lograr conectar con varias maquina.

Donde en **"Key": "12345ABCDE"** y **Content** que dice **"localhost"** es mi maquina de desarrollo y me funciona perfectamente aqui el proyecto lo abro desde la solution

Donde en **"Key": "VWXYZ12345"** y **Content** que dice **"pruebaiis_d.LTL.com.ve"** es un sitio web de IIS donde lo publique y funciona perfectamente pues es una url a la cual ingreso y me hace la búsqueda

Pero donde en **"Key": "ABCDE12345"** y **Content** que dice **"111.10.10.111.localhost"** es la misma maquina donde esta publicado en IIS pero lo estoy abriendo desde la Solution y la busqueda no la hace

Anexo codigo

```
{
    "Authorizations": [
        { 
            "Key": "12345ABCDE",
            "Value": {
                "Kind": 1,
                "Content": "localhost",
                "CanViewPrices": true,
                "StoreId": "A001"
            }
        },
        { 
            "Key": "VWXYZ12345",
            "Value": {
                "Kind": 1,
                "Content": "pruebaiis_d.LTL.com.ve",
                "CanViewPrices": true,
                "StoreId": "A001"
            }
        },
        { 
            "Key": "ABCDE12345",
            "Value": {
                "Kind": 1,
                "Content": "111.10.10.111.localhost",
                "CanViewPrices": true,
                "StoreId": "A001"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Para lograr conectarme a ese archivo JSON, desde la solution tengo el siguiente CODIGO,

donde en **ApiKey: "ABCDE12345"** es la llave del Archivo JSON que tiene por Nombre **Key**

los **ApiKey** que estan comentados son los que mencione arriba y funciona

```
function doneTypingSearch() {
    $('.producto').autocomplete({        
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                
                url: "http://190.10.10.190/wsinterfaz/Rest/PublicService.svc/FindProducts",
                type: "POST", contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                crossOrigin: true,
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    Search: request.term,
                    ApiKey: "ABCDE12345",// localhost desde la IP 191.11.11.191


                    // ApiKey: "VWXYZ12345", DESDE 191.11.11.191 // pruebaiis_d.LTL.com.ve

                    //ApiKey: "12345ABCDE", //localhost // 190.10.10.190

                    Count: 100,
                    StartIndex: 0,
                    StoreId: "A001"
                }),
                success: function( data ) {
           
                    var res = data;
                    var availableTags = [];
           
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.Products.length; i++) {
                        var principio = data.Products[i].ActiveIngredient != "" ? " - " + data.Products[i].ActiveIngredient : "";
                        var precio = data.Products[i].LastFullPrice != 0 ? " Precio: "+ (data.Products[i].LastFullPrice).toFixed(2) : "";
                        var opt = data.Products[i].Description + principio + precio;
                        availableTags.push({ label: opt, id: data.Products[i].Id, indice: i });
                    }
                     
                    
                    response( availableTags );
                },

            });
        },
        minLength: 3,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            desbloquearGuardar();
            var sapCode = ui.item.id;
            $(this).prop("disabled", true);
            $($(this).nextAll("input[type=hidden]")).val(sapCode || "");
        },
        open: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
        },
        close: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
        }
    }, function () {
        
    }, 300);
}
```

La solucion a mi problema es que no se que colocar en **"Content"** para lograr realizar la búsqueda pues he intentado con lo siguiente:

Manera 1 **"Content": "111.10.10.111\localhost"**

Manera 2 **"Content": "111.10.10.111.localhost"**

Manera 3 **"Content": "111.10.10.111"**

Manera 4 **"Content": "localhost"**

Ninguna de esta me ha servidor

```
{ 
                "Key": "ABCDE12345",
                "Value": {
                    "Kind": 1,
                    "Content": "111.10.10.111.localhost",
                    "CanViewPrices": true,
                    "StoreId": "A001"
                }
            }
```

ANEXO IMAGEN DONDE EN ESTAS 2 FUNCIONA

**"Key": "12345ABCDE" y Content que dice "localhost"**
Y

**"Key": "VWXYZ12345" y Content que dice "pruebaiis_d.LTL.com.ve"**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ANEXO IMAGEN DONDE NO FUNCIONA

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradeceria mucho si me ayudaran con este pequeño y gran detalle

Answer (score 0):

Logre hacerlo coloque en Content "localhost" y me trajo los productos :)

Basicamente asi trabaje desde otra maquina de desarrollo y el proyecto lo abro desde Visual Studio siempre sera localhost

```
{
    "Authorizations": [
        { 
            "Key": "12345ABCDE",
            "Value": {
                "Kind": 1,
                "Content": "localhost",
                "CanViewPrices": true,
                "StoreId": "A001"
            }
        },
        { 
            "Key": "VWXYZ12345",
            "Value": {
                "Kind": 1,
                "Content": "pruebaiis_d.LTL.com.ve",
                "CanViewPrices": true,
                "StoreId": "A001"
            }
        },
        { 
            "Key": "ABCDE12345",
            "Value": {
                "Kind": 1,
                "Content": "localhost",
                "CanViewPrices": true,
                "StoreId": "A001"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Agrégale la linea de código donde hiciste la modificación.

Comment: Listo @RamiroBarone